# Scrapy crawling issue

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a python as well as scrapy noob and facing a problem which I cant seem to figure out a way out of. 
I am trying to scrape ingredients of a recipe from www.tarladalal.com with my scrapy spider code as

```
import scrapy
import os
import re
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


from tarla.items import

 from tarla.items import TarlaDalal

class TarlaDalalSpider(CrawlSpider):
     name = "tarla"
     start_url = ["http://www.tarladalal.com/recipes-for-breakfast-151",
             "http://www.tarladalal.com/recipes-for-accompaniments-244",
              ]

     rules = (
       # Follow pagination
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'\?pageindex=\d+',)), follow=True),

    # Extract recipes
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'[0-9]r',),deny = r'/display-comments*'), callback ='parse_recipe', follow=True)
)

    def parse_recipe(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        recipe = TarlaDalal()
        ing = []
        # name
        try:
            recipe['name'] = hxs.select("//h1[@itemprop = 'name']/text()")[0].extract().strip()
        except:
            pass

        # ingredients
        ingredient_nodes = hxs.select("//div[@id = 'rcpinglist']/span[@itemprop = 'ingredient']")
        for ingredient_node in ingredient_nodes:
            try:
                quantity = ingredient_node.select("span[@itemprop = 'amount']/text()").extract()[0]
                name = ingredient_node.select("div[@itemprop = 'name']']/text()").extract()[0]
            except:
                continue

            ingred= Ingredient()
            ingred['name'] = name
            ingred['quantity'] = quantity
            ing.append(ingred)

            recipe['ingredients'] = ing
        try:
            recipe['prep_time']= hxs.select("//time[@itemprop = 'prepTime']/text()").extract()[0]
        except:
            pass
        try:
            recipe['cook_time'] = hxs.select("//time[@itemprop = 'cookTime']/text()").extract()[0]
        except:
            pass
        return recipe
```

Given this script Scrapy instead of crawling closes the spider immediately after launching the telnet console, without even fetching  first request for start url

While if I debug scrapy using command line parse with the specific spider

```
    spider parse --spider=tarla "http://www.tarladalal.com/recipes-for-breakfast-151"
```

it essentially does scrape of all the available links needed from the url page

I am using scrapy v 1.0.3 with python 2.7

Any pointers towards why this issue would crop up would be really helpful. Also first time poster here my apologies for any inadvertent lack of information

Comment: You have the class `TarlaDalalSpider` defined twice. The class `Ingredient()` isn't defined anywhere.  I'd also recommend updating from the deprecated `HtmlXpathSelector` class to the new `Selector` class.  Lastly, in your recipe["name"] selector, list item selection ([0]) should happen after the .extract(), not before.  Based on this, your code, as written, should be throwing some exceptions.

Comment: My apologies , I have not redefined the class in the original script was an error on my part while copying it over here , as I mentioned in the question , Let me try removing the try part in name selection and see if that is an exception , but still in the logthe of scrapy shouldnt there be atleast one webpage fetch for this exception to be encountered?